# require js load function from a modul

Tags: javascript, jquery, module, requirejs, undefined

despite i found already some answers i could not figure it out where i made the mistake in loading the module with require js, i always get the error Uncaught

> TypeError: undefined is not a function

at the line where i try to call the function in the zoom.js file

> myZoomingFunctions.minSize();

here my code:

main.js

```
require.config({

    baseUrl: 'js/libs',

    paths: {
        'jquery': 'jquery-1.9.1',
        'myDraw': '../draw',
        'myZoomingFunctions': '../zoom'

    }
});
require(['jquery', 'myDraw'], function ($, myDraw_ref) {
  var myDraw = new myDraw_ref();
});
```

draw.js

```
define(['myZoomingFunctions'], function (myZoomingFunctions_ref) {

 var myZoomingFunctions = new myZoomingFunctions_ref();

return draw = function() {
 myZoomingFunctions.minSize();
}

});
```

zoom.js

```
define([], function () {


  return zoom = function() {

    function minSize(){ 
            alert("minSize called");
      }
}

});
```

thanks!

Answer (score -1):

i figured out, maybe if someone else have the same problem, here is the solution:

main.js

```
require.config({

    baseUrl: 'js/libs',

    paths: {
        'jquery': 'jquery-1.9.1',
        'myDraw': '../draw',
        'myZoomingFunctions': '../zoom'

    }
});
require(['jquery', 'myDraw'], function ($, myDraw_ref) {
  var myDraw = new myDraw_ref();
});
```

draw.js

```
define(['myZoomingFunctions'], function (myZoomingFunctions) {

return draw = function() {
myZoomingFunctions.minSize();
myZoomingFunctions.maxSize();
}

});
```

zoom.js

```
define([], function () {
     return {

            minSize: function() {

               alert("min Size called");
            },

             maxSize: function() {
              alert("max Size Called");
            }  
        }  
});
```